# Ubuntu Backup Solution to backup a networked mounted drive to the local disk, and with a gui

Tags: backup

I'm running an internal network LAMP server on ubuntu 10.10. I have another ubuntu running on an older ppc g5 with a 640gb drive in it. I'd like to run some software on that G5 that does some snapshot and archiving over the network of the data running on my lamp server.

Ideally i'd like something that has a simple admin gui that allows me to browse and restore files.

What would be a good piece of software?

Something like the MAC OS X Time one

Thanks

Jason

Comment: Look here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/2596/comparison-of-backup-tools There is a great comparison of backup tool, many of them with a Gui.

Answer (score 2):

Just installed http://backintime.le-web.org/

It's awesome. works what how I wanted it to work, however

I haven't been able to browse a network drive yet. Gotta work out how to mount the network drive. Any suggestions?

thanks

Comment: Network support is the main weak point in Back in Time. See https://bugs.launchpad.net/backintime/+bug/453169. Is the network drive always available? If so you can add it to your /etc/fstab file so it mounts on boot. You'd have to use NFS or Samba as SSHFS doesn't support hard links, which are required for Back in Time. There's a good guide on the fstab file at http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=283131 If the network drive isn't always available it's a bit trickier.

Comment: There's no network support but by following adam R's link you can find a way to mount it in the /media dir. Will get back to you guys once i've implemented it

Comment: There's a "gotcha" with backintime - "dot" files are excluded by default. If you want your home directory's dot files, use backintime's Settings->Exclude and remove .*

Answer (score 1):

I always used *rsync* or *rsnapshot*, but some colleagues advice me to use **Bacula**. http://www.bacula.org/

Bacula is an Open Source program for backup solution in a company/enterprise environment with a complete Gui for all the backup,restore and maintenance operations.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to backup my remote files using back in time. Mounted the remote location in my explorer, then from within back in time, I included the mounted desk [find it under home/.gvfs]. Now take your snapshots.

Answer (score 0):

I really like Deja Dup, the interface is really simple and support network backup
(also in the cloud with services like Amazon S3 )

Install: [deja-dup](http://packages.ubuntu.com/deja-dup) [image: Install deja-dup]

Obviously backup in filesystem or external drives is also supported.

Screenshots:

[image]
[image]

**Note that Deja Dup supports incremental backups!**

Answer (score 0):

To have an alternative tool to Time Machine you can install **Back in time** from his GitHub https://github.com/bit-team/backintime or PPA doing:

- Ubuntu stable PPA

  `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bit-team/stable
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install backintime-qt4`
- Ubuntu testing PPA

  `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bit-team/testing
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install backintime-qt`

You need to mount the networked drive without touching the `fstab` config file or using `autofs` and configure properly:
    
    `sudo apt-get install autofs`

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Can you please explain exactly how to install and use those tools? Don't just put links and leave a half-answer; include steps (and screenshots if possible).

Comment: The links are outdated. I refresh the links and add some info about the installation procedure.